# Symfony3: Execute code every 24 hours

Tags: php, symfony

I just started a project and I want the server to update the SQL row 24 hours after, for example when a user submit the form, the SQL row will be updated 24 hours after.

Any idea ?

Comment: Which OS do you run under? Have you got your code in a separate comand/script? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Create a file that do this update, then add an entry on windows task manager or linux crontab to execute this file.

Comment: I'm running on Linux, yes and I tried to build a custom command but this is not what I want.

Comment: Create a cron but add it to the application source code (`src/App/Console/UpdateProjectCommand.php`) so you have it in the project, and use repository class if you're using an ORM. Then run it in the cronjob: `0 12 * * * /path/to/app/bin/console app:project:24Update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas, in order of difficulty:

(1) Create a cronjob, and query the timeframe you are interested in. -24h +-X min for example, run the cronjob every X min.

Mark processed rows, and exclude them from further queries.

(If you will allow some self advertisement: https://github.com/Padam87/CronBundle :))

(2) Create a long running process, and do the same in a never ending loop, use a task runner like `pm2` to keep it alive.

(3) Rabbitmq has a plugin to schedule messages. It is probably overkill, but would be an exciting task. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/